# Outer measure and Lebesgue measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am studying about measure theory using the book Measure, Integration and Real Analysis (Axler, 2020).

Concerning the outer measure and Lebesgue measure, the author proved that when restricts to the $\sigma$ algebra of Borel subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, the outer measure is a measure.

Then he defined the Lebesgue measure:

> [image]

But then, he stated that "Unlike outer measure, Lebesgue measure is actually a measure" (as shown below):

> [image]

His words make me so confused because he have just proved that outer measure is a measure, and then he seems to mean that outer measure is not "actually" a measure. Could you please explain me what the author means?

Comment: You have said that he proves that the outer measure is a measure "when restricts to the $\sigma$ algebra of Borel subsets of $\mathbb R$", and that the Lebesgue measure is subject to this same restriction. You have not quoted him as saying that the unrestricted outer measure is a measure.

Comment: @MarkBennet: Thanks for your response. What I mean is that the author state that the Lebesgue measure and outer measure are basically the same thing (on the $\sigma$ algebra of Borel subset) but then he states that they are not the same thing. I mean the "measure" only makes sense when we restrict it to some $\sigma$ algebra (because we define the measure on a measurable space). Could you please explain further your idea ? Thank you

Comment: The Lebesgue Measure and Outer Measure are defined on different collections of subsets of $\mathbb R$ as more fully explained in peek-a-boo's answer. Whether you have a measure or not can depend on the domain of definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall that the outer measure $m^*$ is defined on the entire power set of $\Bbb{R}^n$, while $m:= m^*|_{\mathcal{L}(\Bbb{R}^n)}$; i.e we define $m$ to be the restriction of the outer measure $m^*$ to the Lebesgue sigma-algebra. Clearly, from the very definition itself, it's clear that $m\neq m^*$ as functions. Afterall, how can they be equal, they have different domains (one is defined on the whole power set, while one is defined on a strictly smaller sigma-algebra).

The author is claiming that $m$ is a measure (i.e $m(\emptyset)=0$, $m$ is a non-negative function and is countable additive), while $m^*$ is only countably subadditive. You write

> His words make me so confused because he have just proved that outer measure is a measure.

No, there is nowhere the author proves $m^*$ is a measure, only that **once you restrict the domain** of $m^*$ to a slightly smaller sigma-algebra, then that restriction is a measure. These are completely different statements and there is no contradiction going on here.

So, the use of "actually" is just as an extra emphasis, because $m^*$ is an outer measure, but it has the nice property that when you restrict to a smaller sigma-algebra, the result is a measure.